# Special way to load UITableViewCell from nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

This is a way i invented for loading custom cells

1) i use my UITableViewCell class extension

```
//.h

@interface UITableViewCell (Extended)

+ (id) cellWithClass:(Class)class;

+ (id) cellWithClass:(Class)class fromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName;

@end

//.m

+ (id) cellWithClass:(Class)class
{
    return [UITableViewCell cellWithClass:class fromNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(class)];
}

+ (id) cellWithClass:(Class)class fromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName {

    NSArray * nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];

    NSEnumerator * nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
    NSObject * nibItem = nil;

    while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {

        if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:class]) {
            return nibItem;
        }

    }

    return nil;
}
```

2) create custom UITableViewCell subclass, with a .nib of the same name (CustomCell.xib) where i have all the outlets connected

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * labelSmth;

- (void) setupWithTitle:(NSString *)title;

@end
```

2) in the CustomCell.xib using Interface builder i drag a UITableViewCell and make it class of CustomCell (with reuse identifier CustomCell)(i dont set the File owner)...  and than do the UI styling, connect outlets etc...

3) than load it like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * identifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [UITableViewCell cellWithClass:[CustomCell class]];

    }

    [CustomCell setupWithTitle:[self.titles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

**IS THIS APPROACH OK? This worked for many projects, but iam not sure about the reuseidentfier and about the fact if the cell gets proper reused... **

iam also not sure about this

```
NSArray * nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];
```

as i pass owner self in a class method...

also Apple has came up with

```
- (void) registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuse;
```

how could this fit my approach?

and also how to use a custom reuse identifier, like if i wanted a method

```
+ (id) cellWithClass:(Class)class fromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to invent something new for this. It's been invented for you already. And what you have invented is a common anti-pattern for loading custom cells.

Enumerating the nib contents to get hold of the UITableViewCell in the nib is not the correct approach.

You should define and outlet to your UITableViewCell in the files owner of the nib that you created the UITableViewCell (usually a UIViewController).

Then you can access that cell using this pattern:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell"; //this should also be specified in the properties of the UITableViewCell in the nib file
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.myCustomCellOutlet;
        self.myCustomCellOutlet = nil;
    }   

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how does your sample gets affected with the new - (void) registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuse; ?

Comment: What do you mean? @applefreak